# When JEditorPane will not do. JRex, JRex wherefore are thou JRex? 

Tags: java, user-interface, browser

IDEA: Implement a recent web browser into a java application (for saved offline, non server content).

---

The question is this: can I have a java application implement a webbrowser with jquery / html / css support within a java program?

---

So I am asking anyone who has played with JRex for advice: I want to know how complicated will it be to integrate an open source webbrowser into java. I am not all that keen on the idea of compiling Mozilla from source build. Is there a ready made compiled version?

Is there a simplified method to have latest compiled version (most current in terms of support for HTML css & javascript), and integrate that into an application?

Also: I appreciate the amount of work required to support for HTML4 nevermind 5, and CSS2 compliance. How close is JRex to that?

Application: My intention with the webbrowser is to render a webpage from offline content. It will not need to be online content, and will simply be for file based displays = e.g. file:///C:...

Does the webbrowser have to be wrapped into a server to function, e.g. to pass files to the browser to render is how complicated? I am not keen to have to implement Jetty or another server type application just for this.

---

If JRex is not the solution... what then? Is it possible to start a browser implementation within Java and can Java interact with the information and traverse the Dom?

Or alternatively is there .hta equivalent in recent browsers like firefox?

Comment: Your question is way too vague and meandering. Are you asking "What approach should I take w/r/t my application's UI?" - that's a question that doesn't have anything approaching an objective answer without you specifying more constraints. Is it "What are my options for embedding a web browser component in a Java desktop applications, given [requirements]?" Or "How do I expose my code to / call Javascript functions in [embedded HTML renderer]?"

Comment: Yeah I know. I rewrote the entire question.

Comment: I'd also like to know why you need the Java backend; or what you mean by "HTA equivalent". This would let people propose alternatives to the embedded web browser approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to have the embedded browser interact with your application code, you could try the SWT [Browser control](http://help.eclipse.org/helios/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/swt/browser/package-summary.html), it's actually maintained as opposed to JRex. Browser uses either WebKit or Gecko or embedded IE as appropriate, or lets you choose which one you want, so it should run jQuery and familiar Javascript. And since SWT is a JNI library to begin with they probably already have guidance on how to deploy an app that uses JNI.

You can feed HTML into the control from a string ([*example*](http://git.eclipse.org/c/platform/eclipse.platform.swt.git/tree/examples/org.eclipse.swt.snippets/src/org/eclipse/swt/snippets/Snippet136.java)) or a java Url - which can point to local files or resource files in your JAR, which I assume will let you split your app into different files.
To call Java code, you need to expose it as Javascript functions. [*example*](http://git.eclipse.org/c/platform/eclipse.platform.swt.git/tree/examples/org.eclipse.swt.snippets/src/org/eclipse/swt/snippets/Snippet307.java) 
To manipulate the HTML from Java code, you need to call Javascript functions from Java. [*example*](http://git.eclipse.org/c/platform/eclipse.platform.swt.git/tree/examples/org.eclipse.swt.snippets/src/org/eclipse/swt/snippets/Snippet161.java)

To make the previous two tasks easier, you might want to look into a JSON library to simplify passing around complex data.

Answer (score 0):

Does it have to be implemented within a Java program? Could you let the user use the default browser on their machine (ie does it matter what browser)?

If not would use the [Java Desktop API](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/J2SE/Desktop/javase6/desktop_api/).

```
 if (desktop.isSupported(Desktop.Action.BROWSE)) {
            txtBrowserURI.setEnabled(true);
            btnLaunchBrowser.setEnabled(true);
        }
```

If you are using Java 1.5 try http://javadesktop.org/articles/jdic/